# Pipenv shell session notebook printing wrong environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables, pipenv

In my "regular"/starting/parent(?) session, I have an environment variable `TOKEN` that is `token1`.  However, I want to set a different TOKEN for the `pipenv shell` environment I'm running.  When I'm in the shell session, I set a new value for `TOKEN` to `token2`.  When I launch a Jupyter Notebook and use the `os` module to get what I would expect to be `token2`, I end up getting `token1`.

I don't know why this is happening but I tried to work around it by using a `.env` file (with the `token2` value) in the directory I'm in and using both `decouple.config()` and `os.getenv()` to get the values in there.  The return was still `token1`.

Ideas?

Comment: How do you set new value to TOKEN in shell? `TOKEN=value` or `export TOKEN=value` ?

Comment: I did `export` and also set it in the `.env` file.

Comment: Any change the kernel in your Jupyter Notebook is still referencing the 'regular'/starting/parent environment?

Comment: @BartBarnard How would I determine that?

Comment: `!which python` in a Notebook cell should point to the path of the virtualenv.